# Unknown ordinal value [46] for enum class error with Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums

I'm developing a Java web App using Hibernate and Spring. I define an `Enum` as follow:

```
public enum FeatureType implements ParentEnumInterface{

    VAL0(0, "VAL0"), VAL1(1, "VAL1"), VAL2(2, "VAL2"), VAL3(3, "VAL3"), VAL4(4, "VAL4"), VAL5(5, "VAL5"),
    ...
    VAL43(43, "VAL43"), VAL44(44, "VAL44"), VAL45(45, "VAL45"), VAL46(46, "VAL46");

    private String translate;
    private FeatureType(int ordinal, String translate)
    {
        this.translate = translate;
        setEnumOrdinal(this, ordinal);
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name();
    }

    private static void setEnumOrdinal(Enum object, int ordinal){
        Field field;
        try{
            field = object.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("ordinal");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(object, ordinal);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new RuntimeException("cannot update enum ordinal", ex);
        }
    }
    public String getTranslate()
    {
        return translate;
    }


}
```

Because I have very `featureType` and it's possible I delete some of them in developing time, I define `ordinal` for all `featureType`.

I use `FeatureType` Enum in my entity as follow:

```
public class MetaData implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long Id;

    private FeatureType featureType;

    // Getters And Setters
}
```

My application works perfectly as long as `FeatureType` members are less than 46. However, when I add the 47th member, an error occurs as follows:

[image]

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ordinal value [46] for enum class [ir.javan.calk.enums.FeatureType]

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ordinal value [46] for enum class [ir.javan.calk.enums.FeatureType]

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ordinal value [46] for enum class [ir.javan.calk.enums.FeatureType]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    ir.javan.calk.util.SimpleCorsFilter.doFilter(SimpleCorsFilter.java:36)
root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown ordinal value [46] for enum class [ir.javan.calk.enums.FeatureType]
    org.hibernate.type.EnumType$OrdinalEnumValueMapper.fromOrdinal(EnumType.java:391)
    org.hibernate.type.EnumType$OrdinalEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:381)
    org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:107)
    org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)
    org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
    org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2924)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1695)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1627)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1509)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:719)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:949)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2550)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2366)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2361)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:124)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1623)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:374)
    org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:396)
    ir.javan.calk.dao.MetadataDaoImpl.getMetadata(MetadataDaoImpl.java:45)
    ir.javan.calk.service.MetadataServiceImpl.getDescribeFeatureType(MetadataServiceImpl.java:61)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy664.getDescribeFeatureType(Unknown Source)
    ir.javan.calk.controller.MetadataController.getDescribeFeatureType(MetadataController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    ir.javan.calk.util.SimpleCorsFilter.doFilter(SimpleCorsFilter.java:36)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.27
```

What's the problem?

Comment: It is just a gues, maybe is modifiing the ordinal not a so good idea.

Comment: I Use this manner according to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449334)

Answer (score 4):

First let me say something: I belive that it is (let me express it friendly) **a not so good idea to manipluate the enum ordinals!**

---

I guess the problem is that you have a gap in the enum ordinals. And you used the ordnials to map them with hibernate. So Hibernate use the `OrdinalEnumValueMapper`. The code used by this mapper is:

```
private Enum fromOrdinal(int ordinal) {
    final Enum[] enumsByOrdinal = enumsByOrdinal();
    if ( ordinal < 0 || ordinal >= enumsByOrdinal.length ) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(
              String.format("Unknown ordinal value [%s] for enum class [%s]", ordinal,enumClass.getName()));
    }
    return enumsByOrdinal[ordinal];
 }

 private Enum[] enumsByOrdinal() {
      if ( enumsByOrdinal == null ) {
           enumsByOrdinal = enumClass.getEnumConstants();
           ...
      }
      return enumsByOrdinal;
 }
```

You notice that this code obtain the list of enum values in an array by `T[] getEnumConstants()` (a method of `Class`) and then access that array at the position of the ordinal. BUT YOU CHANGE THE ORDINAL, so it will access the wong value. - If you are lucky, it will try to access an index that is not in the array and an exception occures, it you have a bad day it will find have a value at that index, but then it could be the wrong one (because of a gap).

**Solution:** Remove the ordinal maniulation and use `@Enumarated(value=EnumType.STRING)` instead